# Mac OS X: the last blank line in the php error Yii2?

Tags: php, macos, line

Source Yii2 PHP runs on window 7, but not on Mac OS X.

**Yii2 PHP error:**

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'f' (T_STRING) in /Volumes/Khac Nha/xampp/htdocs/thaiminh/vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php on line 15

Here is the source PHP, line 15 is blank:

[image: Here source PHP]

Or error follow:

[image]

I at last deleted the file space, and it ran.

**I discovered it was missing PHP closing characters `?>` at the end of the file, but why for is it running Windows, while it isn't on Mac?**

I run web document root in NTFS drive.

How to fix?

**UPDATE:
Thank all!
I fix using dos2unix.**

Comment: Maybe in some other file there is `f` character before `<?php` opening tag?

Comment: I have check, not charater f.

Comment: Did you try moving the project in a non-NTFS drive? There are plenty of people having problems with NTFS on OSX - if you need to be compatible with windows you can use exFAT.

Comment: also missing PHP closing tags are not a problem if there is no content after that in the file

Comment: do you use GitBash or anything like that? can you open this file in question in vi? you should be able to see the special character causing issue for you. One more thing - you don't a closing tag there, that is not what's causing error for you...